# finding document based on different input mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
let bondNumber1 = "100000000001"
let bondNumber2 = "00000001"
let bondNumber3 = "000001"
let bondNumber4 = "0001"
```

I need to choose the user whose contain these bondNumber in their data and I want them separately, like the user contain bondNumber1 value retreived separately and the user who contain bondNumber2 value retreived seperatly and so on.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "601af5cadea1ae126ac56bab"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "bondNumber": "100000000001",
  "date": {
    "$date": "1970-01-19T15:52:59.587Z"
  },
  "type": "sold"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "601af80fdea1ae126ac56bac"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "bondNumber": "100000000002",
  "date": {
    "$date": "1970-01-19T15:53:00.172Z"
  },
  "type": "sold"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "601afc0be3abcd1b474c546a"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "bondNumber": "100000000003",
  "date": {
    "$date": "1970-01-19T15:53:01.192Z"
  },
  "type": "sold"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "601afe7ce3abcd1b474c546b"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "bondNumber": "100000000004",
  "date": {
    "$date": "1970-01-19T15:53:01.816Z"
  },
  "type": "active"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
let inputBondNumbers = ["100000000001","00000001","000001","0001"]
let users = await db.collectionNameHere.find({
         bondNumber: {$in : inputBondNumbers}
})
```